# CartThrob and multiple currencies on separate domains

Tags: cartthrob

I have two nearly duplicate sites accessed from two domains – .com.au and .co.nz – run from a single non-MSM installation of EE where different custom fields are used to display info and prices specific to each site.

Given that both sites are using the same templates and entries, what's the best way for taking orders in the currency specific to the domain they're ordered from?

Do I need to use separate gateways for each domain or is there a single gateway that can handle both?

Or is there a tag or parameter that can be used to in either add_to_cart_form or checkout_form that can specify which currency to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is:

```
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' id='currency_code' value='XXX'>
```